# Does Microsoft use WCF or EF in their products?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I'm failed to use WCF in my product as it isn't real time enough and we have to combine WCF + WCF data service which it is a bit convoluted.
I'm wondering if MS really uses their technologies for their products. Could anyone please point out at least one microsoft product that uses any of WCF or EF related.
it is clear to me that the technology will be soon disappear if they are not using the technology.

Comment: Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 provides a WCF Data Service (OData) interface and a Standard WCF interface for its API's.

Comment: Given that WCF has been around since 2006/2007, and it's 2012 now, I sincerely doubt that it is going to "disappear soon", even if it's not leveraged heavily by MS in their own consumer products.

Comment: I'm glad that you have pointed out CRM using WCF. I've been working with Navision Axapta, then Microsoft Axapta and now Microsoft Dynamics AX and we don't seem to see any WCF in AX which is the MS biggest ERP product. I agree with you that WCF has been 5 years, it may be in the same situation with visual basic 5/6 activeX document, which it isn't around today if you still remember. I don't mind to go a long way or combining WCF+WCF data service but I want to be sure our product last atleast 10-15years before we decide to change the core technologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WCF is core feature of many MS products including:

- Microsoft Dynamics product suite (CRM, NAV)
- Microsoft SharePoint Server and Project Server
- Microsoft BizTalk and Host Integration Server - WCF is used for exposing functionality and there are multiple enterprise adapters for non MS products like IBM WebSphere MQ, Tibco EMS, Tibco Randezvous or Oracle database based on WCF
- WCF can be also used for communication with Microsoft Exchange but I'm not sure if Exchange directly exposes WCF services instead of old ASMX.
- You can also use WCF to communicate with SQL Server Broker (but you need a channel for that).

Entity framework is a different story - I don't think it is used in any of Microsoft Server products. Entity framework is supposed to be used for websites and business level applications which have to be delivered quickly. EF now belongs to ASP.NET MVC / Azure product family which directly targets custom development. Azure is also used for SAAS deployments of MS server products but that is a separate area.

Mentioned MS products targets performance, scalability and extensibility through additional APIs - because of that they usually build either abstraction suited for their needs or use database directly (including a lot of logic implemented directly in the database).

Comment: Great answer, I feel much better that we see some use of WCF technologies in MS core products. We'll need to do more homework to see how these products are using the WCF technologies at their core. Your last part is interesting when we think about building a piece of software that can survive 10 or 15 years, eg. the core of SQL server would never change but rather improving.

Comment: Could you please point out where Navision is using WCF in their core component? there is Navision Application server that does not seem to use WCF, there is some communications with message queue but this isn't making use with WCF. offcourse, if we think about any third parties or add-ins, it can be anything.

Comment: Why do you say that EF is supposed to be used for applications that have to be developed quickly? Does it mean that if you dont have a have constraint on an application its not recommended to use EF. I would recommend EF based on other criteria, e.g stronly typed LINQ queries, generation of classed based when database exist (database first) and generate database if classes exist (code first), maintainability due to strong typing

Comment: It wasn't meant to criticize your reply, only that I find the greatest benefit of of EF(or any ORM) is not to have SQL strings in your code.

Comment: @Filip: But that benefit has damn big performance cost and that is the reason why you don't find ORM in most of enterprise level products. Anyway having SQL strings in code is not such a big problem if you use good abstractions. Over time I found that having L2E queries all over the code base is much worse then it was with SQL strings before.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I have not yet formed my own opinion on performance cost but if you think that the reason for not using an EF in many enterprise apps I will keep that in mind. After using ORMs for only a couple of years the performance seems good enough and I dont see why it cant be used with good results.